# Objective C: Adding Images on different pages

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new to trying to create a book app adapting the page-based application of the new xcode just using the single view app, because it is quite confusing learning the template.

i found this code and i am trying to replace the HTML content of this work to UIImageView but i failed.

```
- (void) createContentPages
{
    NSMutableArray *pageStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        NSString *contentString = [[NSString alloc]
                                   initWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body><h1>Chapter %d</h1><p>This is the page %d of content displayed using UIPageViewController in iOS 5.</p></body></html>", i, i];
        [pageStrings addObject:contentString];
    }
    pageContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:pageStrings];
}
```

what i am trying to is to display different images per page.

here is what i did. (i know it is so wrong i just tried it)

```
- (void) createContentPages
{
    NSMutableArray *pageStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        NSArray *photos = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"p1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"p2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"p3.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"p4.png"],
                        nil];
        [pageStrings addObject:photos];
    }
    pageContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:pageStrings];
}
```

and it has UIWebView in each page. is it possible that if i replace it with UIImageView it will run?

Here's the rest of the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createContentPages];
    NSDictionary *options = 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
     [NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin]
                                forKey: UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];

    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] 
                           initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
                           navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                           options: options];

    pageController.dataSource = self;
    [[pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];

    contentViewController *initialViewController = 
    [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers =  
    [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

    [pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers  
                             direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward 
                              animated:NO 
                            completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[pageController view]];
    [pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (contentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    // Return the data view controller for the given index.
    if (([self.pageContent count] == 0) || 
        (index >= [self.pageContent count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    contentViewController *dataViewController = 
    [[contentViewController alloc]
     initWithNibName:@"contentViewController" 
     bundle:nil];
    dataViewController.dataObject = 
    [self.pageContent objectAtIndex:index];
    return dataViewController;
}

- (NSUInteger)indexOfViewController:(contentViewController *)viewController
{
    return [self.pageContent indexOfObject:viewController.dataObject];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:
(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:
                        (contentViewController *)viewController];
    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:
                        (contentViewController *)viewController];
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageContent count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

on subclass

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [webView loadHTMLString:dataObject 
                    baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All time you may use the pictures inside HTML page using the HTML tag `<IMG>`. So, no the reason to use UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Use your createContentPages() method with this one small change (UIImage alone don't represent anything you can put on a "view"  Instead you need to use a UIImageView which holds UIImages):

```
- (void) createContentPages
{
    NSMutableArray *pageStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        NSArray *photos = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                        [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"p1.png"] autorelease],
                        [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"p2.png"] autorelease],
                        [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"p3.png"] autorelease],
                        [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"p4.png"] autorelease],
                        nil];
        [pageStrings addObject:photos];
    }
    pageContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:pageStrings];
}
```

You can use the code from the main controller (the big block of code that you posted).

The only changes you'll need to make are in what you're calling the "subclass." (really it's the UIPageViewController that handles showing the actual pages).

In that UIPageViewController remove the "webView" (UIWebView).  This is probably done in the .xib file (doesn't look like it's added in the code).  Then make, viewWillAppear in the UIPageViewController look like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.view = dataObject;

}
```

That should do the trick.  Basically, we are no longer using the UIWebView to show HTML data, and instead just adding the dataObject (a UIImageView) as a subview of the UIPageViewController.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Paste the method called on page turn please

Comment: there you go, i posted the rest of the codes. i just found it somewhere and i am trying to learn it for a long time.